Creating a new column based on the unique values of two other columns
I have a dataframe with columns A, B, and C where column B has three unique values 'a', 'b', and 'c'. I want to create a new column for my data frame in the following way. Given two values in B like 'a' and 'b', create column D such that for each group in A, we put Ca - Cb  where Ca is the integer in C corresponding to a. The integer Cb is defined similarly.
import pandas as pd
data = {'A': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'], 
        'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b' , 'c'],
        'C': [10,   20,  7,   30,  25,  7,   60,  50,   7],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I want to create the following dataframe
output = {'A': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'], 
          'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b' , 'c'],
          'C': [10,   20,  7,   30,  25,  7,   60,  50,   7],
          'D': [-10, -10, -10,  -5, -5,  -5,   10, 10,    10] 
          }


Why did the values in C change? Is this a mistake?

sorry, I'll fix it now

IIUC, you can pivot, eval, and map:
df['D'] = df['A'].map(df.pivot(index='A', columns='B', values='C').eval('a-b'))

Variant with pipe:
df['D'] = df['A'].map(df.pivot(index='A', columns='B', values='C')
                        .pipe(lambda x: x['a']-x['b']))

Or creating a Series after set_index and performing indexing:
s = df.set_index(['B', 'A'])['C']
df['D'] = df['A'].map(s['a']-s['b'])

Output:
   A  B   C   D
0  X  a  10 -10
1  X  b  20 -10
2  X  c   7 -10
3  Y  a  30   5
4  Y  b  25   5
5  Y  c   7   5
6  Z  a  60  10
7  Z  b  50  10
8  Z  c   7  10


Thank you, I think the indexing method in the fastest one, right? I am working with large data set.

I believe it should, but better try with your own data. If you have more values than a/b/c but only use a/b you could also pre-filter the useless rows

In my actual dataframe, the pair of ['B', 'A'] does not create unique indexing. I encounter to the following error.
"Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"
But there is another columns, say F, creates unique indexing [B, A, F]

But when I add F, all values in column D become NaN

That's difficult to give you a workaround without an exact example. However, I see two options: adding F as extra index, or removing the redundancy with aggregation/reduplication. You might want to open a follow up question
